# What's the current state of the art about the mythical (or very real, your choice) Web Operating System?

Tags: cloud

I remember hearing many times about how it will happen real soon now (TM).

So, as of now, what seems to be happenning on the Web as Operating System front?

Can you share links pointing to current work in this area?

Comment: While interesting, it seems any answer might be subjective, or require extended debate.

Comment: @Stefan: There, no more subjectivity

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but check out the [Synology Disk Station](http://www.synology.com/products/dsm_livedemo.php?lang=enu) Live Demo. I think it comes pretty close to what you describe. Also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_desktop) has some nice examples.

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os) is coming along quite nicely, [Hexxeh](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) has some builds available. I've used them on an old Acer Aspire One netbook and its reasonably usable, providing you have a network connection and everything you use is in 'the cloud'

Comment: +1 you beat me to it. I've tried it and it works, but it's slow as s*** and doesn't support wireless network configuration yet.

Comment: I have the wireless configuration working fine (need to login once with a wired connection first), although I did replace the wireless card in my netbook with a more common Intel based one so maybe the the drivers support is not as broad as it could be. Speed wise, yeah it's not great but it is getting better with each build